# Analogue to adjacency matrix for simplicial complexes

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory, algebraic-topology, simplicial-complex, adjacency-matrix

So for graphs we have adjacency matrices to represent the relations between vertices. Could such a generalised object exist for simplicial complexes?

I guess it would need to be some sort of tensor, where restricting to the "first" dimension would give the adjacency matrix for the one skeleton but then the higher dimensional connections are also encoded.

I've been trying to think about what such an object would be, perhaps an $n \times\dots\times n$ array but I don't see how this could also preserve lower dimensional relations too.

Comment: For a simplicial complex it's just a sequence of incidence matrices (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_matrix), one connecting each dimension to the next dimension.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan how would this even work just going to 2-complexes? Say we have the complete graph on $n$ vertices, we know what the first incidence matrix is. What would columns and rows even represent for the second? Pairs of vertices, i.e. potential edges?

Comment: The first incidence matrix is between vertices and edges, and the second one is between edges and faces.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan but this isn't actually how it works even for graphs is it? An adjacency matrix is between vertices, where a $1$ indicates the two vertices are joined by an edge and a $0$ if not.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed I think if $i$ goes from 1 to the dimension of the complex, you need a set of $n_i \times \cdots \times n_i$ - arrays where the $i$-th array has dimension $i+1$.  $n_i$ is the number of $(i-1)$-simplices contained in your complex. If there is a $i$ simplex connecting $i+1$ simplices of lower dimension, define corresponding entry in the $i$-th matrix to be 1 and otherwise 0.

An simple example of a 1-complex can be a triangle with three vertices $\{A,B,C\}$, three edges $\{a,b,c\}$ and one surface. The two matrices would be:
 $$
X = 
 \begin{matrix}
 & A & B   & C   \cr
A & 0 & 1 & 1 \cr
B & 1 & 0 & 1 \cr
C & 1 & 1 & 0 \cr
\end{matrix}
$$

$$
Y[a]=
 \begin{matrix}
 & a & b   & c   \cr
a & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr
b & 0 & 0 & 1 \cr
c & 0 & 1 & 0 \cr
\end{matrix}
$$
$$
Y[b]=
 \begin{matrix}
 & a & b   & c   \cr
a & 0 & 0 & 1 \cr
b & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr
c & 1 & 0 & 0 \cr
\end{matrix}
$$
$$
Y[c]=
 \begin{matrix}
 & a & b   & c   \cr
a & 0 & 1 & 0 \cr
b & 1 & 0 & 0 \cr
c & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr
\end{matrix}
$$

As you note this graph is complete and nevertheless has many zeros in its second matrix. I don't know if this procedure has been studied at any time and think the approach with incidence matrices is more straight forward.